# How to write a correlated subquery for the below one?

Tags: subquery

Can anyone help me to write co-related subquery for the below non-correlated subquery?

`SELECT e.emp_no,e.last_name FROM employees e,dept_emp d 
WHERE e.emp_no = d.emp_no 
AND d.dept_no = (SEELCT dept_no FROM dept_emp WHERE emp_no =
    (SELECT emp_no FROM employees WHERE first_name = "Margareta" AND last_name = "Markovitch"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the answer for the above query :

> Select E.Emp_No,E.Last_Name From Employees E Where Exists 
>                                  ( Select Dept_No From Dept_Emp D Where E.Emp_No=D.Emp_No)
>                                  And emp_no In (Select emp_no From Employees Where First_Name='Margareta' And Last_Name='Markovitch');